# Add class to dropdown based on selected Option AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to AngularJS. I have a dropdown with few options. When the selected option matches a condition, I want to change the text color of the dropdown's text. I tried the following.

```
                    <select class="primary-select form-control"
                        id="rbDefinition" name="rbDefinition"
                        qa-name="rbDefinition"
                        [(ngModel)]="selectedBdef"
                        [ngStyle]="{'color': selectedBdef.disabled ? '#888' : '#555'}"
                     >                            
                    <option *ngFor="let rdef of rbDefinitions"
                            [disabled]="rdef.disabled"
                            [ngValue]="rdef">{{rdef.title}}
                    </option>
                </select>
```

The HTML generated is

```
   <select class="primary-select form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="rbCaregory" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="Category" ng-reflect-model="[object Object]" ng-reflect-qa-name="Category" style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136);">
          <option value="0: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-disabled="true" disabled="">Select Category</option> 
          <option value="1: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]">Design</option> 
           <option value="2: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]">Functional</option>
     </select>
```

As the style is being applied on the  all the options have text color of #888. But I want only the option with disabled attr to appear in color #888.

Also tried

```
    <option *ngFor="let rdef of rbDefinitions"
             [disabled]="rdef.disabled"
             [ngValue]="rdef"
             [ngStyle]="{'color': rdef.disabled.disabled ? '#888' : '#555'}"
     </option>
```

But as the styles in the  is what is being applied and the color style given in option is being ignored.

Comment: Could you create a demo showcasing the issue. There isn't really enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AJT_82 I have added more context with more code. Please check now

Comment: Did you try adding a class?

Comment: Yes with the same logic. In place of styles, i tried to add class. But it behaves like how ngStyle behaves.

Comment: I think the reason why all the option have the same style because the function is asking if one of the option is disabled, and there's at least one of them that is, so the style is "#888".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to do this in CSS?

Because, since you identify the disabled element with '[disabled]="rdef.disabled"' which I'll assume refer to your ng-model where there's "disabled: ture/false" for each option (having your javascript as well would help btw)

you really just need to add this to your CSS :

```
option, select {
    color: #555;
}
option:disabled {
    color: #888;
}
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

  .controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [{
        title: "option #1",
        disabled: false
      },
      {
        title: "option #2",
        disabled: false
      },
      {
        title: "option #3",
        disabled: true
      },
    ]
  });
```

```css
option,
select {
  color: #555;
}

option:disabled {
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCtrl as ctrl">
  <select class="primary-select form-control" id="Options" name="Options" n-model="options">
    <option ng-repeat="item in options" ng-disabled="item.disabled" ng-value="item">
      {{item.title}}
    </option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

For implementing it you can use angular directive

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.directive("checkAvailability",function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var isActive = (attrs.active == "true");
           if(isActive){
             element.css('color', '#555');
             element[0].disabled = false;
             
           }else{
            element.css('color', '#888');
            element[0].disabled = true;
           }
        }
    }  
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{name: 'one', id: 30, active : true },{ name: 'two', id: 27, active : true },{ name: 'threex', id: 50 , active : false}];
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem">
      <option ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"  data-active="{{item.active}}" check-availability>
        {{item.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    
  </div>
```

Check the above code

FYI : adding style attribute  for options may not work for IOS/Mac devices.

thanks